# kex_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, ssh

When trying to connect to my aws EC2 instance , I keep getting the same error:

```
kex_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset
```

The command I am running is:

```
ssh -i pemfile ec2-user@ipaddress
```

I have seen other posts, regarding the same query, but most of the answers recommend to reboot the instance, but the comments on them , state that it is a bad method to solve this issue.

So please do advise , thank you!

Btw the other issues were : `kex_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer` ( this includes by peer , while my error doesnt have by peer, so confused about that too)

Comment: were you able to solve it ? having the same issue with lightsail